# How does switch statement work in C?

Tags: c, switch-statement

Could anyone please explain why the output of this code is 4 when x = 0 ( i thought if x is 0, which applies the the `case 0:` and y suppose to be 3 and i'm wrong in this case.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y;

    switch (x) {
    case 0:
        y = 3;
    case 1:
        y = 4;
        break;
    default:
        y = 5;
        break;
    }
    printf("%d", y);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, the best way to see switch() is as a "computed GOTO"

Comment: There should be a list of 'You're a C programmer Harry - when" and 'face palmed because of a fall-through bug in a switch statement you coded' is on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case statements are designed to fall through to the next case in line unless they have a break statement to pull execution out of the entire switch.  In this case you commended out the break statement for "case 0", so execution slipped downward to "case 1" which reassigned y to 4.

Answer (score 3):

After `switch(x)` operation, execution jumps to the corresponding `case N` statement first. Then it executes code after that statement until a) it find the end of the `switch(x)` boundary defined by brackets (`{}`) or b) it finds a `break` statement inside the switch, which ends that switch.

In your case it went through `y=3` down to `case 1`, down to `y=4` and then ended at the `break`.

Answer (score 2):

You commented out your `break;` statement in your first case statement!

So just write this:

(Otherwise when x is 0 or 1 y gets assign to 3 and then 4)

```
case 0:
    y = 3;
    break;
```

A `switch` statement goes to the next `break;` if there is missing one for a `case` statement! An if you forgot all of them :D then it stops at then end of the `switch` statement and all lines get's executed!

Comment: Yes but i need to know how this work when there's no 'break;'

Comment: @Impalerz if there is no break statement it goes until the next one!

Answer (score 1):

Because the `break` is commented out:

```
switch (x) {
 case 0:
     y = 3;
     //break;  <---- commented out.
```

And to every novices surprise execution just carries on from the 'matching' case unless a break (or return) is encountered.

I'm sure it seemed like a good idea at the time and there are some really fruiting coding tricks that exploit it.
Duff's device is the most famous.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device

999 times out of a 1000 it's an annoying bug that will take an hour to find.